# How to change legend order of Pie Chart in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, legend, pie-chart, powerbi-custom-visuals

As for **piechart** in powerBi, currently legend order is set by value. I want to reorder it by alphabet order of legend key. I select specified key (IsReady) and flags and show below graph.

[image]

Here is my sample data.
[image]

Comment: You want False first and then True?

Comment: Yes @mkRabbani, i want reorder by alphabet, so false first with True followed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the sort column by clicking the 3 Dot as shown below-

[image]

Just select the column from list you wants to apply the sorting on and then select the order Ascending or Descending.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine by firstly sort by type then select sort ascending